# Access: Search and Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I'm running a query in access to search a table with two fields of numbers. One field is "Dose" and the other is "Volume". Below I'm searching for the "Dose" when the "Volume" is equal to a value nearest to 2 and dividing by 100 to get the correct units, which works fine.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Table1]![Dose]/100 AS CentiDose 
FROM [Table1] 
ORDER BY Abs([Table1]![Volume]-2);
```

However I want to use UPDATE (or at least that's what I think?) to take this value and insert it into a field of one record in another table ie Table2, record 1, field 1. Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm a novice at using Access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to update an existing row in table2 then UPDATE is what you want, something like

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Field1 = Centidose
WHERE Table2.recordid = x
```

If you need to append a new record to table2, it would look more like

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SET Field1 = Centidose
WHERE Table2.recordid = x
```